# How can I configure scitools.std in mac?

Tags: python, macos, scitools

I tried to do this in my terminal:

```
pip install --user -e \ 
      git+https://github.com/hplgit/scitools.git#egg=scitools
```

But it failed with an error:

```
-bash: git+https://github.com/hplgit/scitools.git#egg=scitools: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

When you type the command in the terminal you remember to omit the '\' ?

```
pip install --user -e 'git+https://github.com/hplgit/scitools.git#egg=scitools'
```

Answer (score 0):

Put quotes around the git URL.

```
pip install --user -e \ 
    'git+https://github.com/hplgit/scitools.git#egg=scitools'
```

Comment: I can't duplicate this problem on my Mac using bash, so unfortunately I don't have another idea what is wrong...